# How can I use Angular material in Bazel-enabled project in my custom library?

Tags: angular, angular-material, bazel

How can I use Angular material in Bazel-enabled project in my custom library?

Here is my code: https://github.com/AkshayC1736/angular-bazel.git

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! this question is liable to downvotes, as your GitHub link points to very long amounts of code. It is better to create a [mcve] of that.

Comment: @MulliganᛜReinstatingMonica  Thanks. but I provided the GitHub link for better understanding of my problem.

Comment: Sure, but that's not what SO is here for. What happens when you go and delete your github? Now you have a question here that 404's and there is absolutely zero context to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add `@npm//@angular/material` to your `ng_module` rule deps (as well as to the `package.json` - `npm i @angular/material`)

There is an example of using Angular Material in an Bazel built Angular app in the rules_nodejs example directory on github here: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs/blob/master/examples/angular/src/shared/material/BUILD.bazel#L11

There's also an example here of using Angular Material, and importing the theme scss, although it may be a little out of date
https://github.com/evertz/bazel-angular-prerender

Comment: Thanks @Matt ,Its working in dev mode but not working in prod mode.
Error: inject() must be called from an injection context
   at injectInjectorOnly$1 (chunk-244276f9.js:432)
   at ɵɵinject$1 (chunk-244276f9.js:432)
    at e (chunk-244276f9.js:747)
    at _callFactory (chunk-244276f9.js:255)
    at _createProviderInstance (chunk-244276f9.js:255)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (chunk-244276f9.js:255)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (chunk-244276f9.js:255)
    at resolveDep (chunk-244276f9.js:255)
    at createClass (chunk-244276f9.js:255)
    at createDirectiveInstance (chunk-244276f9.js:255)